# How to insert additional values in between a GROUP BY

Tags: sql, mysql

i am currently making a monthly report using MySQL. I have a table named "monthly" that looks something like this:

```
  id |         date        | amount
```

---

```
  10 | 2009-12-01 22:10:08 | 7 
  9  | 2009-11-01 22:10:08 | 78 
  8  | 2009-10-01 23:10:08 | 5 
  7  | 2009-07-01 21:10:08 | 54 
  6  | 2009-03-01 04:10:08 | 3 
  5  | 2009-02-01 09:10:08 | 456 
  4  | 2009-02-01 14:10:08 | 4 
  3  | 2009-01-01 20:10:08 | 20 
  2  | 2009-01-01 13:10:15 | 10 
  1  | 2008-12-01 10:10:10 | 5
```

Then, when i make a monthly report (which is based by per month of per year), i get something like this.

### yearmonth | total

```
2008-12   | 5 
2009-01   | 30 
2009-02   | 460 
2009-03   | 3 
2009-07   | 54 
2009-10   | 5 
2009-11   | 78 
2009-12   | 7
```

I used this query to achieved the result:

SELECT substring( date, 1, 7 ) AS yearmonth, sum( amount ) AS total
FROM `monthly` 
GROUP BY substring( date, 1, 7 )

But I need something like this:

### yearmonth | total

```
2008-01   | 0 
2008-02   | 0 
2008-03   | 0 
2008-04   | 0 
2008-05   | 0 
2008-06   | 0 
2008-07   | 0 
2008-08   | 0 
2008-09   | 0
2008-10   | 0 
2008-11   | 0 
2008-12   | 5 
2009-01   | 30 
2009-02   | 460 
2009-03   | 3 
2009-05   | 0
2009-06   | 0
2009-07   | 54 
2009-08   | 0
2009-09   | 0
2009-10   | 5 
2009-11   | 78 
2009-12   | 7
```

Something that would display the zeroes for the month that doesnt have any value. Is it even possible to do that in a MySQL query?

Answer (score 4):

You should generate a dummy rowsource and `LEFT JOIN` with it:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  1 AS month
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2
        … 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  12 
        ) months
CROSS JOIN
        (
        SELECT  2008 AS year
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2009 AS year
        ) years
LEFT JOIN
        mydata m
ON      m.date >= CONCAT_WS('.', year, month, 1)
        AND m.date < CONCAT_WS('.', year, month, 1) + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY
        year, month
```

You can create these as tables on disk rather than generate them each time.

`MySQL` is the only system of the major four that does have allow an easy way to generate arbitrary resultsets.

`Oracle`, `SQL Server` and `PostgreSQL` do have those (`CONNECT BY`, recursive `CTE`'s and `generate_series`, respectively)

Comment: so the only way is to create a new table?

Comment: `@Marky`: or generate the values like in my post. New table is better.

Answer (score 0):

Quassnoi is right, and I'll add a comment about how to recognize when you need something like this:

You want '2008-01' in your result, yet nothing in the source table has a date in January, 2008. Result sets have to come from the tables you query, so the obvious conclusion is that you need an additional table - one that contains each month you want as part of your result.